# Can't connect email mailable to view in laravel modules

Tags: php, laravel

I cant seem to connect my mailable to its blade view.
this is my markdown in the mailable build function:

`->markdown('emails.exmpl');`

I built the blade view inside `Modules\ContactUs\Resources\Views\Emails` calling it `exmpl.blade.php`

however i get this error:

`View [emails.exmpl] not found.`

Answer (score 0):

By default the path is `resources/views/emails/exmpl` but here your blade is in a different module. Might I suggest trying

`->markdown('/Modules/ContactUs/Resources/Views/Emails/exmpl')`

Keep me posted in the comments below.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to specify module on view method use:

```
$moduleName = "ContactUs";

return view($moduleName . "::pages.main");
```

This helped me !